# MySQL - better syntax to compare multiple variables in where-clause

Tags: mysql

My query looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id1 = id2 and id2 = id3 and id3 = id4 and id4 = id5
```

This works, but it gets complicated if there are more ids. Is there any way to shorten this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE (id1 | id2 | id3 | id4 | id5) = id1 
  AND (id1 & id2 & id3 & id4 & id5) = id1
```

`|` is bitwise or
`&` is bitwise and
`^` is bitwise xor

Another option is:

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE ((id1 ^ id2) | (id3 ^ id4) | (id4 ^ id1) | (id5 & id1)) = 0
```

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/bit-functions.html